# How to define a spark Schema for a List of objects i.e. StructType?

Tags: apache-spark, java-8, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I am using spark-sql-2.3.1v with Java 8 in my project. I am trying to define a schema to decode my message consumption from the Kafka stream.

I have

```
class Company{
    String companyName;
    Integer companyId;
}
```

Which I defined as

```
public static final StructType companySchema = new StructType(
              .add("companyName", DataTypes.StringType)
              .add("companyId", DataTypes.IntegerType);
```

But message defined as

```
class Message{
    private List<Company> companyList;
    private String messageId;
}
```

I tried to define as

```
public static final StructType messageSchema = new StructType()
            .add("companyList", List(companySchema)),true)
            .add("messageId", DataTypes.StringType);
```

This is giving error at List. So how should this schema should be defined?

Comment: Did you try `DataTypes.createArrayType(companySchema)`?

Answer (score 2):

Below worked.

```
public static final StructType messageSchema = new StructType()
            .add("companyList", DataTypes.createArrayType(companySchema, false),false)
            .add("messageId", DataTypes.StringType);
```